# More badges for being a site enthusiast

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Granted there are already quite a few badges for community service on this site, I thought, how about ***some more***!

The theme is merging enthusiast/fanatic with suffrage/vox populi. Something like this (names and numbers open to suggestions)

**Enthusiastic Voter** - Voted 20 times per day consecutively for 30 days
**?????** - Voted 30 times per day consecutively for 50 days
**Fanatic Vox** - Use the maximum number of 40 votes consecutively for 100 days

Comment: *Fanatic Vox* sounds pretty cool

Comment: We need a higher class than gold. Perhaps platinum? Or "pure data"?

Comment: Would this result in a lot of random voting for the sake of voting, just to get the badge?

Comment: @psu Whatever argument you put up, you already made it against Suffrage/Vox Populi, yet we have the badges.

Comment: The difference is that with the existing badges, the users just needs to use all the votes they have available in a day; they don't need to keep voting different days to get the badge.

Comment: If something is deemed positive (hence a badge) X times positive goes the same direction doesn't it? Otherwise, why have the badges `suffrage` and `vox populi` at all?

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi: Those badges are meant to *teach* users how to vote well on questions and how the vote limit works. That's why they're only bronze badges. The argument that it encourages random voting was dismissed because it's only awarded once and it's only a set of 40 votes in a single day. With your gold Fanatic Vox badge, you're increasing that to 4,000 votes over a period of 100 days. That's a **lot** more potential damage. **I haven't even voted 4,000 times overall on Stack Overflow.**

Comment: @ani Well that's the problem then isn't it. Just like you've walked past litter every day of your live in the last 11 years and haven't stopped each time to quickly pick it up to deposit in the next trashcan on your way. Vote Vote Vote - this site lives on Votes! `We NEEDZZ more VOTES`!

Comment: We already have badges to encourage people to vote...

Comment: @ani Wait, so are you saying the badges `encourage` people to vote, or `teach` them to vote? Two very different goals...

Comment: Badges encourage positive behavior. A lot of the bronze badges are there simply to teach users about the site, which is definitely a positive behavior.

Answer (score 9):

I remember the time I earned the Vox Populi badge I had a night to myself and decided to spend an above average time on SO finding posts to vote on. While I kept it constructive, towards the end I did start to recognize the subtle urge to skim over posts and vote just to "git r done".

I think these sorts of badges are a bad idea because they will exacerbate that tendency to vote without thinking too much, at least for users who are overly motivated by badges. Especially the fact that they require you to maintain a streak of minimum votes across many days will lead to constructive voting fatigue, as people tire of the task but don't want to give up the time spent voting that they "invested".